# How to create URL Parameters from a list

Tags: python, django, urlencode, urllib

I have a form with multiple select field. It is working through `GET` method.
An example of request parameters generated by the form:

```
action=not-strummed&action=not-rewarded&keywords=test&page=2
```

Note that there is two "action" parameters. This is happening because of the multiple select.
What I want to do is:

- Make a dict from parameters
- Remove "page" key from the dict
- Transform-back the dict into the parameter string

The `urllib.urlencode()` isn't smart enough to generate url parameters from the list.

For example:

```
{
     "action": [u"not-strummed", u"not-rewarded"]
}
```

urllib.urlencode() transforms this dict as:

```
action=%5Bu%27not-strummed%27%2C+u%27not-rewarded%27%5D
```

This is completely wrong and useless.

That's why i wrote this iteration code to re-generate url parameters.

> ```
> parameters_dict = dict(self.request.GET.iterlists())
> parameters_dict.pop("page", None)
> pagination_parameters = ""
> for key, value_list in parameters_dict.iteritems():
>     for value in value_list:
>         pagination_item = "&%(key)s=%(value)s" % ({
>             "key": key,
>             "value": value,
>         })
>         pagination_parameters += pagination_item
> ```

It is working well. But it doesn't cover all possibilities and it is definitely not very pythonic.

Do you have a better (more pythonic) idea for creating url parameters from a list?

Thank you

Comment: request.GET return dict with parameters.
request.GET['action'], for example.

Comment: You can read it with [.lists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use the second doseq parameter urlencode offers:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

So basically, you can pass a dictionary of lists to urlencode like so:

```
urllib.urlencode(params, True)
```

And it will do the right thing.